# MarkLogic XQuery tail call optimization

Tags: optimization, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I rewrote a recursive function that was overflowing the stack to use an accumulator, since I thought ML was optimizing this pattern. However, I'm still getting a stack overflow exception. Is there anything wrong with this function wrt tail call optimization?

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare variable $BATCH-DURATION := xs:dayTimeDuration("P5D");

declare function local:start-times(
  $datetime-start as xs:dateTime,
  $datetime-end as xs:dateTime,
  $acc as xs:dateTime*
) as xs:dateTime+
{
  if (($datetime-end - $datetime-start) le $BATCH-DURATION) then $acc
  else local:start-times($datetime-start + $BATCH-DURATION, $datetime-end, ($acc, $datetime-start))
};

local:start-times(xs:dateTime('1800-01-01T17:45:42'), xs:dateTime('2017-10-10T17:45:42'), ())[last()]
```

Comment: Wondering what you need this function. It sounds like a very inefficient way of finding the 'closest' date, if that is all you need..

Comment: @grtjn It's a boiled down version of a function for generating batches. I was only getting `last()` so anyone testing the code wouldn't have their QConsole overwhelmed with data and lock up the browser.

Comment: Even then, passing through results as argument is not the most efficient method. See my answer for some code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the tail call optimization only works if the return value of the function is untyped.

That is, try:

```
declare function local:start-times(
  $datetime-start as xs:dateTime,
  $datetime-end as xs:dateTime,
  $acc as xs:dateTime*
)
{
```

Hoping that helps.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. If this information could somehow find its way into ML documentation I would upvote 10x (if it were possible).

Comment: FYI, I've filed a doc bug internally.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the to the point answer by Erik (@ehennum), there might be more to say about the code. Even if recursion is needed, there might be smarter ways of doing things. Here some alternative algorithms with metrics alongside:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare variable $BATCH-DURATION := xs:dayTimeDuration("P5D");

declare function local:start-times(
  $datetime-start as xs:dateTime,
  $datetime-end as xs:dateTime,
  $acc as xs:dateTime*
)
{
  if (($datetime-end - $datetime-start) le $BATCH-DURATION) then $acc
  else local:start-times($datetime-start + $BATCH-DURATION, $datetime-end, ($acc, $datetime-start))
};

declare function local:start-times2(
  $datetime-start as xs:dateTime,
  $datetime-end as xs:dateTime
)
{
  if (($datetime-end - $datetime-start) le $BATCH-DURATION) then ()
  else 
    let $tick := $datetime-start + $BATCH-DURATION
    return ($tick, local:start-times2($tick, $datetime-end))
};

let $datetime-start := xs:dateTime('1800-01-01T17:45:42')
let $datetime-end := xs:dateTime('2017-10-10T17:45:42')
return (

  (: original recursive method :)
  let $start-time := xdmp:elapsed-time()
  return (
    local:start-times($datetime-start, $datetime-end, ())[last()],
    xdmp:elapsed-time() - $start-time
  ),

  (: more efficient recursive methode :)
  let $start-time := xdmp:elapsed-time()
  return (
    local:start-times2($datetime-start, $datetime-end)[last()],
    xdmp:elapsed-time() - $start-time
  ),

  (: non-recursive method:)
  let $start-time := xdmp:elapsed-time()
  let $datetime-closest :=
    $datetime-start + (fn:floor(($datetime-end - $datetime-start) div $BATCH-DURATION) * $BATCH-DURATION)
  return (
    (: handle edge case :)
    if ($datetime-closest eq $datetime-end) then
      $datetime-closest - $BATCH-DURATION
    else
      $datetime-closest,
    xdmp:elapsed-time() - $start-time
  )
)
```

HTH!

Comment: Good point. In the original function (before rewriting as tail recursive), I did this, but instead of returning the value, I passed the value directly to a function that spawned a batch - and that still overflowed (like `if *base case* then ... else (xdmp:spawn-function(..., $start-time, ...), *recurse on rest*)`). I suppose if I had just generated all of the start time values with traditional recursion first, then iterated over them to spawn batches, I never would have gone down this path.